# Show different content for logged in(out) users. Django tests

Tags: django

Im following django tutorial and there is [additional ideas](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial05/#ideas-for-more-tests) how to test my code.

> Perhaps logged-in admin users should be allowed to see unpublished
>   Questions, but not ordinary visitors. Again: whatever needs to be
>   added to the software to accomplish this should be accompanied by a
>   test,...

How can I create test to check if logged in User can see Questions witout choices and not logged in not?

```
class QuestionsAndChoices(TestCase):
    def test_user_can_see_question_without_choices(self):
        """
        A Question without choices should be displayed only for logged in Users
        """
        #first make an empty question to use as a test
        empty_question = create_question(question_text='Empty question', days=-1)

        #so we can create choice but in this case we don't need it
        #answer_for_question = past_question.choice_set.create(choice_text='Answer for "Question"', votes=0)

        #create a response object to simulate someone using the site
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))

        #if user logged in output should contain the question without choices
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['latest_question_list'], []) #returns empty querylist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `setUp` method of your test class you can create a user.

```
class QuestionsAndChoices(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='user', password='top_secret')
```

Then in your test method, you can use [`force_login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.force_login) to log the user in, then use `self.client.get()` and make assertions as usual.

```
class QuestionsAndChoices(TestCase):
    def test_user_can_see_question_without_choices(self):
        ...
        self.client.force_login(self.user)

        #create a response object to simulate someone using the site
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))

        #if user logged in output should contain the question without choices
        ...
```